# Measure building lean in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, measurements, orthophoto, building-lean

I was wondering if anyone is aware of any tools that are available to measure building lean in ortho images from within ArcMap. I am aware of calculations and processes that can be used to measure and calculate an angle, but not a specific tool to assist within ArcMap.

Comment: The [Image Measurement widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-image-measurement.htm) was recently released. You can measure using the [Base to Top tool](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-image-measurement.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6DAA120365E74AACA0754143D2001778). It requires an [Image Service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/key-concepts-for-image-services.htm) to function though.

Comment: Thanks @MDHald. So if I understand correctly, the widget would not work on raw ortho tiles (ie: GeoTiff).

Comment: That seems to be the case. I have tried using Raw imagery from the server which is hosted in a Raster Catalog and was not successful. The tool seems to require an ESRI issued Image Service (presumably using a mosaic dataset + image server extension)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @MDHald:

> The [Image Measurement
>   widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-image-measurement.htm)
>   was recently released. You can measure using the [Base to Top
>   tool](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-image-measurement.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6DAA120365E74AACA0754143D2001778).
>   It requires an [Image
>   Service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/key-concepts-for-image-services.htm)
>   to function though.